# -Bash Ubuntu 18.04 $PATH is showing other locations then sys.path inside Python 3

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Hi I am trying to get the geckodriver to be associated with PATH so i can use it in Selenium.

I get the the message from Python: geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH

After adding the location folder where geckodriver(verified executable chmod 777) to PATH in terminal 
I get the location listed($PATH) but it says No such folder or file exists at the end
In Python 3 on running sys.path I do not get the location of geckodriver.

Q1: Is - bash $PATH == Python3 sys.path?
Q2: Anybody have tips to resolve geckodrier Executable needs to be in Path

Comment: `sys.path` is not the `$PATH` of the shell, it is the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Thank you @KlausD. do you know how I can check inside Python 3, what Python can see in PATH?